# Composer packagist Could not find a version of package

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, packagist

I have created a laravel package https://github.com/wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication

My repository is synced with packagist https://packagist.org/packages/wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication

As soon as i push and create a new release it automatically shows up in packagist. The problem is what ever i do i cannot install the repository through composer. I have created two released on gitHub. I have tried all of the below mentioned commands but it won't work. I have seen so many answers on stackoverflow and googled it but i cannot figure out what is the problem.

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong ? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
composer require wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication

composer require wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication dev-master

composer require wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication:1.0.0

composer require wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication "^1.0"
```

**What i want to achieve**

I simply want to `composer require wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication`

**Errors**

[image]

[image]

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication",
    "description": "Firebase token authentication driver for Laravel",
    "keywords": [
        "wcaaan",
        "firebase-token-authentication"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/wcaaan/firebase-token-authentication",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "WCan",
            "email": "wcaaan@gmail.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-tokens": "^1.8",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Wcaaan\\FirebaseTokenAuthentication\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                 "Wcaaan\\FirebaseTokenAuthentication\\FirebaseTokenAuthenticationServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "FirebaseTokenAuthentication": "Wcaaan\\FirebaseTokenAuthentication\\FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFacade"
            }
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Are you using Composer v1, or v2? Have you waited for some time, such that the completely new package could get added to all Packagist-internal structures?

Comment: yivi - apparently i did'nt wait long enough for the repository to list on packagist, it took around 8 hours.